# React Native: Add an icon in header in React Native Calendars

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-calendars

I am looking for a way to add an icon on the right side in the header and use that icon to toggle between month view and week view.

I am using `CalendarList` component for month view and `Agenda` component for weekly view.

I am using this library [react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this one working by wrapping `Icon` inside `TouchableHighlight`and then add some css.

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor={'#EEE'} style={styles.calendarArrowWrapper} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenName')}>
                <Icon style={styles.calendarForwardArrow} type='MaterialIcons' name='view-week' />
            </TouchableHighlight>

calendarForwardArrow: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 40,
        },
    calendarArrowWrapper: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -50,
        right: 10,
        zIndex: 2
    }
```